# In Angular controller's callback, why does parameter have to be named "$scope"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

I'm writing a simple controller in Angular, but there is something I can't figure out.

When writing the callback function, i.e. the second parameter in `module.controller('myController', function($scope){`

I am specifying a parameter, here called `$scope`. I got this code from the Angular documentation.

However, what's strange is that if I change `$scope` to something else, like `abc`, the controller no longer works.

But it should, shouldn't it? Isn't `$scope` just the name of a parameter? For example, for a function like

```
var func = function(abc){
    alert(abc);
}
```

should work even if I change the parameter to `xyz`, like

```
var func = function(xyz){
    alert(xyz);
}
```

Is something else going on here? Is the parameter `$scope` really referring to the global Angular object?

Here's my code overall

```
<html ng-app="MyFirstApp">
<head>

    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <title>My Page</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    var module = angular.module("MyFirstApp", []);
    module.controller('myController', function($scope){
        $scope.airports = {
            "PDX": {
                "code": "PDX",
                "name": "Portland International Airport",
                "city": "Portland",
                "destinations": [
                "LAX",
                "SFO"
                ]
            },
            "STL": {
                "code": "STL",
                "name": "Lambert-St. Louis International Airport",
                "city": "St. Louis",
                "destinations": [
                "LAX",
                "MKE"
                ]
            },
            "MCI": {
                "code": "MCI",
                "name": "Kansas City International Airport",
                "city": "Kansas City",
                "destinations": [
                "LAX",
                "DFW"
                ]
            }
        };

        var p = "pee";
        $scope.airportsArray = function arr(){
            var array = [];
            for (i in $scope.airports){
                array.push(i);
            }
            return array;
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        {{ airportsArray() }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism is called [Implicit Dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-dependencies), It is one of the mechanism used by angularjs to determine what value to be injected to the argument. One mechanism is to make the determination based on the parameter name that is why you are facing the problem when you rename the argument.

This can cause problems if you minify your code, since that may rename your local parameters... so there are other safe methods to inject the values

If you want to give another name for the parameter you can use a different syntax called [Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation), in the below format the actual name of the value to be passed is passed as a string

```
module.controller('myController', ['$scope', function(abc){
}])
```

Another option is called [$inject Property Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation)

```
function myCtrl(abc) {}
myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']
module.controller('myController', myCtrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because Angular uses `Function#toString` to get (a form of) the source code of your function as part of how it works, and it looks in that string specifically for the `$scope` variable in order to apply its automation of things. Here's an example of `Function#toString`:

```js
function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg); // <== Implicit call to Function#toString
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

display(display);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

You can see this in action [in the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js):

```
/**
 * @ngdoc module
 * @name auto
 * @description
 *
 * Implicit module which gets automatically added to each {@link auto.$injector $injector}.
 */

var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
var FN_ARG_SPLIT = /,/;
var FN_ARG = /^\s*(_?)(\S+?)\1\s*$/;
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var $injectorMinErr = minErr('$injector');

function anonFn(fn) {
  // For anonymous functions, showing at the very least the function signature can help in
  // debugging.
  var fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, ''),
      args = fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
  if (args) {
    return 'function(' + (args[1] || '').replace(/[\s\r\n]+/, ' ') + ')';
  }
  return 'fn';
}

function annotate(fn, strictDi, name) {
  var $inject,
      fnText,
      argDecl,
      last;

  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    if (!($inject = fn.$inject)) {
      $inject = [];
      if (fn.length) {
        if (strictDi) {
          if (!isString(name) || !name) {
            name = fn.name || anonFn(fn);
          }
          throw $injectorMinErr('strictdi',
            '{0} is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode', name);
        }
        fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
        argDecl = fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
        forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg) {
          arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name) {
            $inject.push(name);
          });
        });
      }
      fn.$inject = $inject;
    }
  } else if (isArray(fn)) {
    last = fn.length - 1;
    assertArgFn(fn[last], 'fn');
    $inject = fn.slice(0, last);
  } else {
    assertArgFn(fn, 'fn', true);
  }
  return $inject;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the cool tip, but how does it answer the question? Do you mean to say that we need to use `$scope` because it's the only parameter name Angular will recognize?

Comment: @Imray: I thought the question was "In Angular controller's callback, why does parameter have to be named “$scope”?"> This is why, because it gets a *string* of the function and looks for that name. You can change it to something else if you like (by adding an option to your controller), but if you stick to `$scope`, anyone doing maintenance on the code will know what it is.

Comment: Crowder got it now. Thanks